# Foreach is only return first value from array

Tags: php, foreach

I don't understand why `foreach` is only return first value from array.

```
function __EachReturn($Array){
    foreach($Array as $Key=>$Arr){
        $List = $Arr;
    }
    return $List;
}
```

**This is my complete function:**

```
// Styled Function
function Returnstyled($Style){
    $Styled = array();
    function __EachReturn($Array){
        foreach($Array as $Key=>$Arr){
            $List = $Arr;
        }
        return $List;
    }

    foreach($Style as $Key=>$Items){
        $Items = __EachReturn($Items);
            switch($Key){
                case 'CSS':
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<link rel="%s" href="%s" type="%s">',$Items['rel'],$Items['href'],$Items['type']);
                break;
                case 'JS':
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<script src="%s" integrity="%s" crossorigin="%s"></script>',$Items['src'],$Items['integrity'],$Items['crossorigin']);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $Styled;
}
```

**Before I'm using like this:**

```
function Returnstyled($Style){
    $Styled = array();
    foreach($Style as $Key=>$Items){
            switch($Key){
                case 'CSS':
                foreach($Items as $Item){
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<link rel="%s" href="%s" type="%s">',$Item['rel'],$Item['href'],$Item['type']);
                        }
                break;
                case 'JS':
                foreach($Items as $Item){
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<script src="%s" integrity="%s" crossorigin="%s"></script>',$Item['src'],$Item['integrity'],$Item['crossorigin']);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return $Styled;
}
```

So What i did. I don't want to use `foreach` inside `switch case couple of time` so that is why i try to generate nested function i create inside it one more function `EeachReturn` but it's only return first from array.

It has to be return complete array.

Comment: You are overriding the value of `$List` in each execution of your `foreach` loop. You need to declare  `$List` as an array and use `$List[] = $Arr;` in your `foreach`.

Comment: Still, I don't understand the point of this function which transforms an array into... an array.

Comment: why that function though, you could use foreach directly

Comment: `$List = $Arr;` Over writes the scalar variable `$List` so you only see that last one added. Use `$List[] = $Arr;` to build an array _But I see no point in that code being a function

Comment: because without `function` i need to use `foreach` couple of time. so i don't want to do this. Actually i'm new in `php` so I thought my code will be more shrink if i do that.

Comment: You only call that function ONCE so it has no reason to be an function

Comment: I think it might be worth to profile this code to see if it's faster to switch inside the loop or loop inside the switch. I'm not completely sure about it, but I think that looping inside the switch may be faster, because you compare once, then loop over the variables, instead of looping over the variables and then comparing for each variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

store it in `array` and return the array at the end:

```
function __EachReturn($Array){
$List=array();
    foreach($Array as $Key=>$Arr){
        $List[] = $Arr;//change is made here use array to store all values 
    }
    return $List;//return the array.
}
```

**UPDATE**: seeing the

> Before I'm using like this

part from your question, i'll suggest to use your function `__EachReturn`  like this:

```
function __EachReturn($Key,$Array){
    $Styled=array();
        foreach($Array as $key=>$Items){
            switch($Key){
                case 'CSS':
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<link rel="%s" href="%s" type="%s">',$Items['rel'],$Items['href'],$Items['type']);
                break;
                case 'JS':
                        $Styled[] = sprintf('<script src="%s" integrity="%s" crossorigin="%s"></script>',$Items['src'],$Items['integrity'],$Items['crossorigin']);
                break;
        }
    }
    return $Styled;
}
$ItemsList=array();
foreach($Style as $Key=>$Items){
        $ItemsList[] = __EachReturn($Key,$Items);//$ItemsList will consist all the script/link ....
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with complete code kindly check it this is what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar i'll suggest not to use the function, you can directly use  `$Items`(it is the resultant array any how from your function). Let the key in switch be dynamic.You don't need `foreach` here.

Comment: it's did not work i did it. So that is why i use `foreach` if remove foreach it's give me `error` `undefined index like rel,href`

Comment: In that case best option for you is to move your switch case in your function. looks like `$Items` is a multidimensional array. your function `__EachReturn ` is not doing anything just returning the same array.

Comment: can you update your answer with this option as you suggest.

Comment: @MuhammadHamzaNisar check the update d part and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
function __EachReturn($Array){
    $List = []; 
    foreach($Array as $Key=>$Arr){
        $List[] = $Arr; // your loop record was replacing in every loop. now will be captured in array.
    }
    return $List;
}
```

You need to capture foreach data in array.

Answer (score 1):

It is not returning first value from array, it is returning the last value.

```
function __EachReturn($Array){
    foreach($Array as $Key=>$Arr){
        $List = $Arr; //here $List is always getting overwritten by $Arr
    }
    return $List; //when loop finishes, final $Arr is in $List and it is returned
}
```

In order to have all the values returned, store in array as @Suchit suggests.